# OpenERP font-family: 'Free 3 of 9' for barcode is not working in report webkit

Tags: css, fonts, webkit, odoo, mako

I have a problem with WebKit report `.mako` file. when I use:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">${css}</style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        % for o in objects:
            <p style="font-family:'Free 3 of 9';">${o.name}</p>
        % endfor
    </body>
</html>
```

in `.mako` file it is working but if I use

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">${css}</style>   
    </head>
    <body>
        % for o in objects:
            <p class="barcode39">${o.name}</p>
        % endfor
    </body>
</html>
```

and this class is declared in field "css" of `data.xml` in report_webkit

```
.barcode39 {
    font-family: 'Free 3 of 9';
    font-size: 36;
    color: red;
}
```

`font-family: 'Free 3 of 9'` does not work. If I use another `font-family` it is working.
What could be the problem?

I have placed font in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` and also run `fc-cache -fv`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check in your browser's inspector if the correct css is being applied?  The `barcode39` class might be being overridden by something else in the second case since in the first case an inlined style like `style=...` would take priority over other styles.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for quick reply but if i am using different fonts in .barcode39 class other than "Free 3 of 9" then it's working for e.g. "Times New Roman".

Comment: have you installed that font in your system?

Comment: @Mdymade Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Hello, I am not using it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and put the font name into single quotes solved my problem. For example:-

```
style="font-family:'Free 3 of 9';"
```

Comment: Why was "font-size:65px;" included?

Comment: in there, no need to add font size, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a font-face rule to your stylesheet. Something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Free 3 of 9';
    src: url(/usr/share/fonts/truetype/free_3_of_9.woff) format('woff');
}
```